# MySQL between dates query not working properly

Tags: mysql

I'm struggling to make this work, this query should give the deal with the cheapest price between two dates but somehow it's giving the cheapest offer always and it kinda ignores the date

```
SELECT offer_id 
FROM travel_offers o
WHERE price = (
    SELECT MIN(price) as minprice 
    FROM travel_offers om 
    WHERE 
        o.latitude = om.latitude AND
        o.longitude = om.longitude AND
        (o.time_from BETWEEN '2012-07-01' AND '2012-11-31') 
        AND
        (o.time_to BETWEEN '2012-07-01' AND '2012-11-31')
)
```

Comment: Probably because you select all from travel_offers where the price is the lowest one between the dates and location wanted. Therefore if you had the Price 1 for Jan - march, price 2 for april to June and price 1 for July to Sep... you would get 2 rows, for Jan to march and July to Sep... because the first is going back and finding all lines that match those prices.. even if its for a different time and location.

Comment: Does longitude and latitude matter?  If so, I need to change my response.  They should be part of your select if it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT offer_id, MIN(price) as minprice 
FROM travel_offers
WHERE 
    time_from BETWEEN '2012-07-01' AND '2012-11-31'
    AND
    time_to BETWEEN '2012-07-01' AND '2012-11-31'
    and 
    time_from <= time_to
group by offer_id
order by minprice
limit 1
```

Comment: This just gives the min price for each offer during the time frame.  He's looking for the cheapest offer during the time frame.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if longitude and latitude matter:

```
SELECT o.longitude, o.latitude, offer_id 
FROM travel_offers o
WHERE o.time_from BETWEEN '2012-07-01' AND '2012-11-31'
      AND o.time_to BETWEEN '2012-07-01' AND '2012-11-31')
      AND price = (
     SELECT MIN(price) as minprice 
     FROM travel_offers om 
     WHERE 
        o.latitude = om.latitude AND
        o.longitude = om.longitude AND
        (om.time_from BETWEEN '2012-07-01' AND '2012-11-31') 
        AND
        (om.time_to BETWEEN '2012-07-01' AND '2012-11-31')
)
```

If longitude and latitude do not matter:

```
SELECT offer_id 
FROM travel_offers o
WHERE o.time_from BETWEEN '2012-07-01' AND '2012-11-31'
      AND o.time_to BETWEEN '2012-07-01' AND '2012-11-31')
      AND price = (
     SELECT MIN(price) as minprice 
     FROM travel_offers om 
     WHERE 
        (om.time_from BETWEEN '2012-07-01' AND '2012-11-31') 
        AND
        (om.time_to BETWEEN '2012-07-01' AND '2012-11-31')
)
```

Comment: It all depends on whether latitude and longitude matter.  If they do, the first response should work.  Otherwise the second.  The problem was that you were not filtering the offers from the "o" table in your where clause.

Answer (score 0):

> somehow it's giving the cheapest offer always and it kinda ignores the date

I guess your `1time_from` should be `2012-07-01` and `time_to` should be `2012-11-31`.
So you need to correct your condition in `WHERE` clause for `1time_from` and `1time_to` like this:

```
WHERE 
    o.latitude = om.latitude AND
    o.longitude = om.longitude AND
    (o.time_from >= '2012-07-01') 
    AND
    (o.time_to <= '2012-11-31')
```

Comment: You need to filter both the "o" and "om" tables.  In this case the the results would be from the correct date range, but the min price selected could be from outside the date range.